# How to configure Virtualmin to be accessed using Domain name after installation

Tags: apache, nginx, ip, webmin, virtualmin

I installed Virtualmin on my server at a time i wasn't having a domain name. But now i do, how do i configure Virtualmin to be accessed through this domain name that is managed from another server.

Can I simply use a reverse proxy to map the ip to the new domain name in Apache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You will need to point your domain to your Virtualmin server and setup apache to act as a reverse proxy for the domain

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ProxyPreserveHost On
       ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:10000/
       ProxyPassReverse / http:127.0.0.1:10000

       ServerName vps.example.com
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. By default Virtualmin bind to your server's IP and port 10000. You can change that to bind to loopback by editing the `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` and add `bind=127.0.0.1` to it
3. Edit `/etc/webmin/config` add `referers=vps.example.com` to allow Virtualmin to serve the page otherwise it will give you an error
4. By default Virtualmin allows access to the root user of your system. To add other users edit `/etc/webmin/miniserv.users` and add the new user.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a Virtualmin question at all, unless I don't understand the question. This is just a basic DNS question.

You don't need to proxy anything. Just point the domain name at your Virtualmin server's IP address (if you're using the DNS services of your registrar or some other DNS hosting service), or set the glue records to point to your Virtualmin server (if you're using the DNS features in Virtualmin).